# How to add textFileds in Dropdown Reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, textfield

I want to add textField - autocomplete in Dropdown? Could you help me how to do it?
[image: The exist Dropdown]

The source code in here: [**Source Code in Sanbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-grothendieck-2h49r?file=/src/ShowDelta.js:0-3900)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Material-UI, you can use their autocomplete component with a TextField as input, have a look at the "Combo box" here:
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#combo-box